# Splashscreen - Accessing Label and Progressbar

Tags: c#, winforms, progress, splash-screen

I have some trouble accessing the ProgressBar and a certain Label in from my splashScreen. I made an own Form for the screen. In my Form1 I have the following method:

```
    private void sign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        splashScreen splScreen = new splashScreen();
        Thread thrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(loadingScreenStart));
        thrd.Start();
        splScreen.percentage.Text = "0%";
        var logIn = new LogIn(this);
        logIn.checkUserInput(this);

        thrd.Abort();
    }

      public void loadingScreenStart()
    {
        Application.Run(new splashScreen());
    }
```

In my LogIn class I did:

```
       public String checkUserInput(object sender)
    {
        splashScreen splScreen = new splashScreen();
        //won't change my Label and PrpgressBar
```

I know it's probably because I create a new instance of the Form so it's empty but how to do this right? I don't know... Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Yes that would be probably the same. I generally had no problems with that. Here in this case I create a new Thread. That's my problem. So I guess it's a little bit different than just accessing controls of another Form?

Comment: Are you trying to access the progressBar from any form other than the form you've created the Splash screen

Comment: Yes. That's the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same requirement I too had where I need to use the same object but was having a limitation where i cannot use the static class. For that i have created a static object of the class and using lock. Try if it solves your requirement.

```
    private static splashScreen m_instance = null;
    private static object m_instanceLock = new object();

    public static splashScreen GetInstance()
    {
        lock (m_instanceLock)
        {
            if (m_instance == null)
            {
                m_instance = new splashScreen();
            }
        }
        return m_instance;
    }
```

And whenever you want to create the object or access the already created object, you just need to give as:

```
SomeClass someobj= SomeClass.GetInstance();
```

Comment: Where to put that in? Why do I need a lock? I don't know what SomeClass is. Tried to put that into the class where I need it but it changes anything

Comment: You can have it in your Form class.

Comment: Can you give me an example related to my code? Do you mean the SplashScreen Form? Then SomeClass would be the SplashScreen Form? I now put the code into my splashScreen Form and in my LogIn class I did: SomeClass someobj= SomeClass.GetInstance(); but that changes anything - The splashScreen Instance is still null.

Comment: If you are having my code#1 in your splashScreen.cs then you should call splashScreen scr=splashScreen.GetInstance(); whenever you want to access the object.

Comment: I did that. It works when I create a new instance (tried it with the debugger) The problem is somehow the Thread. I start a new one (wrote it in my code above) and this doesn't work. When I try to put the GetInstance method into the "Application.Run" method he tells me that it was called from another Thread.

Comment: Ok Ok I created a "GetInstance" where I run the application and put that method in. Now it works fine! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Another short question. Your example works but when I hit the button a second time then he can't access the discarded object anymore. Is there a possibility with your code to solve this problem?